# Constraint propagation using Projection rule

Tags: constraint-satisfaction, constraint-programming

I've found this example of constraint propagation using projection rule 
[image]

We have

```
C = { x1 ≠ x2, x1 ≥ x2 }

< C; x1 ∈ {1,2,3}, x2 ∈ {1,2,3} >
```

They say that applying propagation rule, does not give any simplification.

**I'm not sure why this is the case. Shouldn't we get?**

```
< C; x1 ∈ {2,3}, x2 ∈ {1,2} >
```

Other steps in the example, make sense that to me, e.g.

```
< C; x1 ∈ {2}, x2 ∈ {1,2,3} >
```

produces

```
< C; x1 ∈ {2}, x2 ∈ {1} >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apply the propagation rule to a *single* constraint.

The rules are defined in such a way that they can be applied efficiently. 
Otherwise, by applying the "generalized propagation rule" you could declare that a SAT instance is unsatisfiable in a single step.